# How can I delete a line from a plot by clicking on the legend using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I have this plot that i created with matplotlib, How can I make invisible  a line from a plot by clicking on the legend ? I am using a python file

```
def detect (df_abs,a,b):
    
    X = df_abs.iloc[:, a:b].to_numpy()
    l = X.shape[0]
    D = np.zeros((l, l))
    idx = range(len(X))
    D = np.maximum(D, D.transpose())
    d = D.sum(0) / l
    t= np.dort(d)[np.where(diff > c * np.median(diff))[0] + 1].min()
        return df_abs.iloc[np.where(d >= t)].index

def out (df_abs, a, b, c):
    o= detect(df_abs, a, b, c)
    colors = 'red'
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    plt.plot(df_abs.to_numpy()[:, 1:].T, 'blue')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit to use `Seaborn`

This edit is to use Seaborn instead of just Matplotlib so that you don't have to plot each line individually and manually label each line. First, I will melt the dataframe so that the column names become values  in a new column that I am going to call `Test`. This way, I can use the column names as the input value for Seaborn's `hue` feature. Then, I have to adjust my `onpick` function to account for Seaborn's label schema. With this code, everything should work automatically and you shouldn't have to edit or add anything. Also not the inclusion of the `index` column. This is important as it will be used as your `x` value in the plot after melting the data. **ALSO** ... I updated the code to use visible instead of changing the alpha, now you can toggle the line on and off by clicking on the legend:

```py
def onpick(event):    
    legend_label = event.artist.get_label()   
    
    label_length = int(len(ax.get_lines())/2) # Seaborn uses 2 labels for 1 line, we only want to use the second label
    for x in range(label_length):
        
        if legend_label == ax.get_lines()[x+label_length].get_label():
            if ax.get_lines()[x].get_visible():
                ax.get_lines()[x].set_visible(False)
            else:
                ax.get_lines()[x].set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw()
    
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

y = {'aa': [12,15,20,15,2,10,6,8], 'bb' : [12,15,20,15,2,5,9,15] , 'cc' : [10,15,19,15,2,7,9,15] ,
    'dd' : [10,15,20,16,2,5,2,15] ,
    'ee' : [12,12,20,15,2,7,9,5],'index' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(y)

# Melt the data frame so that we can use the columns names (called 'Test' here) as a value for Seaborn's "hue" function
df_melt = df.melt(id_vars=['index'],var_name='Test', value_name='Values')


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(data=df_melt, x='index', y='Values', hue='Test', alpha=1)

for legend in plt.legend().get_lines():
    legend.set_picker(5)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

Are you using Jupyter Notebook or just a `py` file?

If you're using Jupyter Notebook, you can do something like this, it will set the `alpha` of the line you click on to 0. This way, if you want, you can set it up to show the line again at some point (where as `.remove` would completely remove the line from the figure):

```
%matplotlib notebook # matplotlib magic to make interactive plots work in JNB

# Your 'onpick' event handler, tells the graph what to do when clicking on the legend
def onpick(event):    
    legend_label = event.artist.get_label()
   
    # If the label of the legend matches that of the line, then set the alpha to 0
    for x in range(len(ax.get_lines())):
        if legend_label == ax.get_lines()[x].get_label():
            ax.get_lines()[x].set_alpha(0)
    
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = {'aa': [12,15,20,15,2,10,6,8], 'bb' : [12,15,20,15,2,5,9,15] , } 
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
df = pd.DataFrame(y,x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.aa, label='aa') # line 1
ax.plot(df.bb, label='bb') # line 2

# Set up the picker for the legend elements
for legend in plt.legend().get_lines():
    legend.set_picker(5)

# Activate/connect the graph to the onpick function
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

If you're working in a `py` file, use this code instead. The main difference is  `fig.canvas.draw()` being needed to actually update the plot after clicking on it.

```py
def onpick(event):    
    legend_label = event.artist.get_label()
   
    for x in range(len(ax.get_lines())):
        if legend_label == ax.get_lines()[x].get_label():
            ax.get_lines()[x].set_alpha(0)
            fig.canvas.draw()
    
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = {'aa': [12,15,20,15,2,10,6,8], 'bb' : [12,15,20,15,2,5,9,15] , } 
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
df = pd.DataFrame(y,x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.aa, label='aa')
ax.plot(df.bb, label='bb')

for legend in plt.legend().get_lines():
    legend.set_picker(5)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

Original Graph:
[image]

After `bb` is clicked:
[image]

After `aa` is clicked:
[image]

Comment: thanks you i am using file .py , i am trying with more lines and it is not working , can you help me ?

Comment: It works fine for me, did you make a unique label for each of your lines?

Comment: @shira , check the edit, this should ensure that no matter how many lines you add in the dataframe, you will be able to hide them on legend click.

Comment: @shira check the edit, I also updated it so that you can toggle the lines on and off

Comment: can you check my plot , i edited it . is it working for you ?